# Trying to get difference of dates with carbon laravel

Tags: laravel, php-7, php-carbon, laravel-5.6

I have been trying to get the difference of two dates with carbon so i can calculate the percentage spent, but it keeps outputing 0

> The below is meant to get the difference from the start date and end date.

```
  public function validityMeter($start_date, $end_date){

    $start_date = Carbon::parse($start_date);
    $diff =$start_date->diffInDays($end_date);

    return $diff;


}

public function percentageMeter($start_date, $end_date){


    $diff = Carbon::parse($start_date);
    $diff = $diff->diffInDays(Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"));       
    $multiple = $diff * 100;
    $percentage = $multiple / $this->validityMeter($start_date, $end_date);

    return $percentage;
}
```

> The the second method (percentageMeter()) is meant to get the difference from the current date and start_date after which i will use the value of both methods to get the percentage.

**Blade template**

```
 <div class="progress progress-xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: {{$obj->percentageMeter($booking->start_date, $booking->end_date)}}"> </div>
                  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function type($type){

    // dd(Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"));
    $booking = Booking::where("approve", true)
                        ->where("end_date", '>=', Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"))
                        ->where("plan_type", $type)
                        ->get();
                        // dd($booking);
    $obj = new Plan;

    $counter= 1;
    return view("admin.plan.type")->with("booking", $booking)
                                    ->with("counter", $counter)
                                    ->with("obj", $obj);
}

$start_date  = 2018-05-06 00:00:00;
$end_date = 2018-12-30
```

Comment: Which of the differences returning zero?

Comment: The last method, @MuhammadNauman    **$diff = $diff->diffInDays(Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"));**

Comment: use `$diff = $diff->diffInDays(Carbon::now());` and check

Comment: Still zero, I have tried already before and just did again and it returned zero.@MuhammadNauman

Comment: what is your start_date?

Comment: Just added it now to the question description at the bottom

Comment: Got it now? You are calling `Carbon::now()` in the second function so `$start_date` and `Carbon::now()' both are the same dates. Just put different start date and you will be good to go.

Comment: Yes! you are correct, I resolved it with your help, can you please answer this in the answer section so I can choose it as the correct answer @MuhammadNauman Thanks a thousand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Carbon::now()` in the second function so `$start_date` and `Carbon::now()` both are the same dates. Just put different start date and you will be good to go.